# Proper use of echo json_encode(array('error' => false/true.

Tags: php, json

I am building a function that is suppose to answer a jquery ajax call. I am quite new to PHP and have newer learnt how to properly use echo `json_encode(array('error' => false/true;`. In this specific case want to json encode an array of arrays called `$list`. My code:

```
<?php
 if (!empty($_GET['id'])) {
   $id = $_GET['id'];

   try {
     $objDb = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=blankett', 'root', 'root');
     $objDb->exec('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');

     $sql = "SELECT * FROM `forms2` where `master_id` = $id";
     $list = ($objDb->query($sql));

     foreach ($list as $row) {
        $out = array(
            '<tr>' . 
             '<td><a href="'.$row['link_form'].'">'.$row['name_form'].'</a></td>'.
             '<td>'.$row['date_added'].'</td>' . 
            '</tr>');
     }
     echo json_encode(array('error' => false, 'list' => implode('', $out)));

    /*** close the database connection ***/
    $objDb = null;
   }
   catch(PDOException $e)
   {
     echo $e->getMessage();
   }
 } else {
     echo json_encode(array('error' => true));
 }
?>
```

So the question is in general how do you use `json_encode(array('error' => false/true;`and how would I use it in this specific case?

Comment: New to PHP and using PDO instead of MySQL_*? +1

Comment: yes, quite new to php over all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of your loop only assigns the last row retrieved from **$list** to **$out**. Secondly implode does not give you an array instead it takes an array as a parameter and returns string delimited by the delimiter you provide.

[php.net/implode](http://php.net/implode)

here is what you are trying to do:

```
     $out = array();
     foreach ($list as $row) {
       $out[] = '<tr><td><a href="'.$row['link_form'].'">'.$row['name_form'] .   
               '</a></td><td>'.$row['date_added'].'</td></tr>';
     }

     echo json_encode('error' => false, 'list' => $out);
```

or if you are trying to pass a string instead of an array then use implode as you did on `$out`

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this:

```
   $result = true;

    echo json_encode(array("error"=>$result
                               ));
```

and then:

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "yourfile.php",
    data : "data1="+yourdata1+"&data2="+yourdata2,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
    var error = data['error'];
    if(error === false){
    //do something                                                  
    }
if(error === true) {
    //do something else     
}
   }
      });//end ajax
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can use json_encode directly with your data without having to "implode" it or anything like that.

If $out was an array of arrays, then your code:

```
echo json_encode(array('error' => false, 'list' => implode('', $out)));
```

Would produce:

```
{ result: false, list: 'Array,Array,Array' }
```

You should instead just allow json_encode to do it's job:

```
echo json_encode(array('error' => false, 'list' => $out));
```

Which would give you:

```
{ result: false,
  list:
   [ [ 1, 2, 3 ],
     [ 4, 5, 6 ],
     [ 7, 8, 9 ] ] }
```

The previous comment regarding your loop is important, however. Your loop reassigns the $out variable on each iteration. You definitely want to add the []= instead of just =.  That is a shortcut in PHP that means "push this onto my array".  It's actually a shortcut for [array_push()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

```
foreach ($list as $row) {
  $out []= array('<tr><td><a href="'.$row['link_form'].'">'.$row['name_form'].'</a></td>  <td>'.$row['date_added'].'</td></tr>');
}
```

And finally, your table row doesn't *have* to be an array, unless that's what you wanted.